# Does disabling 'The Nether' improve server performance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, performance

I am setting up a public Minecraft server and have no real use for [The Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether).

I am wondering whether disabling this area will:

- Make a large difference to the server backup size
- Give a noticeable drop in server memory usage

Is it actually worth disabling, or are the differences too minimal to bother doing so?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you do disable the nether your users won't be able to produce potions you need nether wart and blaze rods, neither of which are available in the overworld.

Comment: Considering the Nether is 64 times smaller than the Overworld, I don't imagine it making much of a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sure it will make more space on your hard drive since you don't load another map on your server but anyway that you have 1 , 2 or 3 maps on your server the thing to consider is where the peoples load chunks from it.

So if a user is in the overworld and another in the nether, the same load is use to keep the chunk loaded for those users.

In conclusion, depends how many worlds you have the thing's most important is how much chuck is loaded into the RAM. So you should keep the nether open if you have enough space on your hard drive to keep it alive and keep the backups.

Answer (score -2):

Yes removing the nether should improve performance

Comment: What reasons do you have to believe so?

Comment: Removing the nether decreases server storage need and the need for resources to be used for loading it.